# Why so much geometry in principia and others

Tags: soft-question, history

I was recently reading 'On the the shoulders of giants' by stephen hawking and looked at many physics(mechanics) problems solved by Copernicus,Newton etc. why is there so much of geometry used by them. I mean, most of the problems are solved using pure math and not much physics. Why is this?

Comment: Physics as we know it had not been invented yet. Literally. The first "laws of physics" were the one Newton formulated. For the first time physical phenomena could be described in mathematical terms (instead of the philosophical description that had been the norm since Aristotle)

Answer (score 1):

Newton formulated calculus, so before his time, it was either geometry or difficult algebra.

Comment: What was the difficult algebra

Comment: What I mean is that the problem you wanted to solve (like the orbit of the moon) is difficult to accurately predict using just algebra. It is easier with calculus.

Comment: I think it was an attempt more to mimic "the glory of geometry that from those few principles, brought from without, it is able to produce so many thing" (as Newton said in the *Principia*) rather than for actual calculus reasons...since Leibniz had no problem inventing calculus from Cartesian geometry...